# How do I reach the Hidden Star in Dr Snow?

Tags: joe-danger-2

In the first level of the 'Espionage!' act, Dr Snow, theres a Hidden Star hanging above a low barrier (those you need to duck under) close to the end of the stage.

I never manage to grab it and survive, I assume I have jump above the barrier but the best I managed ended up just landing on top of it and crashing. I seem to be travelling too slow to jump high enough. Is there a good tip for getting that star?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple - double jump. I didn't realize there was one in this game...

Tapping the jump button in mid-air gives you that "extra oomph" needed to clear the jump and grab the star.